# Expand/Collapse Specific Pivot Fields

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need a button that at any click will collapse/expand a certain field in a pivot table.

I have the code for expand and collapse separately.

```
'At click collapse field
Range("B5:B8").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MD").ShowDetail = False

'At another click collapse
Range("B5:B8").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MD").ShowDetail = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for

```
         Set pf = pt.PivotFields(r.PivotField.Name)
     pf.ShowDetail = IIf(r.ShowDetail, False, True)
```